When does the topology of a locally compact abelian group agree with the initial topology of its continuous characters?
I don't know enough topology (and whatever else might be needed) to answer this question meaningful.
At first I thought that since $\hat{G} = \text{Hom}(G,\mathbb S^1)$, the characters will of course remain continuous when we change the topology of $G$ to the initial topology of the characters, and hence the Pontryagin Dual will remain the same and since we can recover $G$ from $\hat{\hat{G}}$ this would imply that the topologies are equal. However, by changing the topology of $G$ we may change the topology on $\hat G$ by 'removing' compact sets, hence possibly changing the topology on $\hat G$.
A class of groups I could think of which satisfy this are $\mathbb R^n$.

Could you please clarify your question. And put it in the body of the question, not just in the title.
